# DrawerNavigator Throwing unknown error

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have the following React-Navigator config:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const MainNavigator = StackNavigator({
            signin: { screen: SigninScreen },
            signup: { screen: SignupScreen },
            home: {
                screen: DrawerNavigator({
                    home: { screen: MapScreen },
                    about: { screen: AboutScreen }
                },
                    { drawerWidth: 200 }
                )
            },
        }, {
                headerMode: 'none'
            })
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MainNavigator />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

When I remove the line:

```
{ drawerWidth: 200 }
```

Then it works, when I place it back I get the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.routeName')

This error is located at:
    in DrawerView (at DrawerNavigator.js:127)
    in Unknown (at createNavigator.js:52)
    in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:210)
    in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:31)
    in SceneView (at CardStack.js:423)
    in RCTView (at View.js:112)
```

If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated. I am not quite sure what is wrong with adding the second parameter to the DrawerNavigator but it seems to break it. In the docs that do say: `DrawerNavigator(RouteConfigs, DrawerNavigatorConfig)`

Regards,
Emir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating your components like so.

React-Native will sometimes throw error `undefined is not an object` if you don't separate the components.

To view full example's code you can visit the link or to test this code, you can scan the QR code provided by the ExpoSnack with your Expo app.
https://snack.expo.io/Hkit-Z4mf

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

const FirstScreen  = require('./screens/first.js');
const SecondScreen = require('./screens/second.js');
const ThirdScreen  = require('./screens/third.js');

const TheDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  TheSecondScreen: {screen: SecondScreen},
  TheThirdScreen:  {screen: ThirdScreen},
}, {
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
});

const TheStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
  TheFirstScreen:  {screen: FirstScreen},
  TheSecondScreen: {screen: TheDrawerNavigator},
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
});

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <TheStackNavigator/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This also seems to be working. If I implement your solution and add the second parameter without adding the keys that John Marshall mentioned then there is no error and it just wont navigate to the screen. If I implement your change with John Marshalls then it works. Strange behavior.

Comment: Oh, that's odd. Glad I was able to help! :)

Comment: Ricky, if you have used React-Navigation DrawerNavigator, do you know how to within the drawer use props.navigation.navigate?

Comment: Is it giving you an `undefined` error? If it does, do `const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;` and then call it like so `() => navigate('TheFourthScreen')` in your `onPress` or in your JavaScript function. Was that your question? But sorry, my first time using DrawerNavigator was when I tried it out after seeing your question haha

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
```

to drawerConfigs